# Which is the movie where aliens are all around us and control our minds?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember a movie where aliens are living around us and look like us too, but then a man finds some glasses through which he can see how they really look. He also finds out that there are subliminal messages in magazines and newspapers.

Does anyone remember the movie's name? I have been trying to find it for a long time.

Comment: I don't think they totally control our minds, they just use their technology to project illusionary images.

Comment: @Mark-Rogers right, i remember they used some kind of antenna to project over real images.

Comment: There was a really awesome game for the genesis called Flashback that had a similar plot.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[They Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live).

[image]

From Wikipedia's plot description:

> Nada quickly discovers the sunglasses have unique properties: they reduce the colors of the world around him to black and white and allow him to see that media and advertising hide omnipresent subliminal totalitarian commands to obey, consume, reproduce, and conform. They also make clear that many people in positions of wealth and power are actually humanoid aliens with skull-like faces.

Comment: It has one of the greatest fight scenes of all time between Roddy Piper and Keith David.

Comment: The movie They Live was based on a short story called "8 o'clock in the Morning". Sadly, they are in the process of remaking it, although the focus will be "less satirical" than the original John Carpenter/Rowdy Roddy Piper classic.

Comment: I've read they are leaving the glasses completely out of it like it was in the short story.

Comment: Do either of you have any sources for the remake?

Comment: [They Live Remake](http://www.slashfilm.com/they-live-remake/)

Comment: More recent, confirming Matt Reeves as the writer/director: http://www.deadline.com/2011/04/matt-reeves-to-writedirect-universal-thriller-based-on-famed-scifi-short-story/

Comment: If you read the original story, you find find definite, strong parallels between it and the *Doctor Who* episodes "The Impossible Astronaut" and "Day of the Moon".

Comment: "They Live" was NO satire.  It was a straight-up commentary on the times.  Broad, perhaps, but hardly satire.